# How do I display a part of column Value in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I Need to Extract the Date from Address column Value . It may be possible that my address column value may have street no , house no , city , state , country, day  etc

But I want to extract only City value or state value or country value . How can i extract that particular if all values are stored in one address column .

I am using mysql database . My structure of that column is -

Column Name - Address

Column Type - varchar(500)

Common Column value -

`Street No-4 , House No-29 , Prabhat Nagar , Ludhiana , Punjab , India , wednessday , 25 may 2014`

There is check available in Code To Check the required values are not empty. Streeno , house no , city , country ,state are required .If any of required fields is empty column will will not be inserted or updated in db and will empty

Code For Date Format is also fixed in code and it will go in this format everytime

Comment: Can you change your design so you have addressline1, addressline2, street, city, postcode etc columns?

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample data. Also, Are you using MySql or Sql Server? they are not the same

Comment: @artm sorry its my restriction i am putting data in one column .Changing structure will need to change many things. if its not possible this way then i will try to change the structure

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sure i am going to update the question with specified required details

Comment: @BhallaCodes keeping multiple data parts in a single column is almost always a bad idea, and by almost always I mean 99.9999... percent of the cases.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I updated the details in answer . Actually address and other things are selected from some map and then entered in db that's why its structured like this . First i will try to explore if we can do it like this way otherwise i need to change number of things

Comment: https://basitaalishan.com/2014/02/23/removing-part-of-string-before-and-after-specific-character-using-transact-sql-string-functions/

Comment: @jpw in over 16 years of programming I've found one case when that was the correct solution. it was keeping a string of comma delimited integers and the only reason it was the correct solution is that this string was not used by the database at all it was the easiest way to use by the application. I guess it can be considered as a single value from the database perspective.

Comment: What happens when there is no house number? How can you tell what part of the string is the city, and what part is the date?

Comment: Q1 - Is the data format always `DD MON YYYY`?
Q2 - Will you always get `street no` and `house number`?

Comment: what about date format ?

Comment: @Utsav date format is fixed it format is set in code

Comment: @ZoharPeled there is check in code that check if there is any house number or if it is empty then it is not saving it in db

Comment: @Utsav yes street no, house no, city ,state , country are required one's

Comment: The best thing you can do is normalize the database. it might involve a lot of work now, but it will save you a lot of pain later on.

Comment: @Zohar Peled . actually rest of db is normalized only this table which is having data that is selecting data from map is not normalized

Comment: Good. that means less work for you.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes i will be dead if db person made this thing in all tables . I am going to look at answers given – Heemanshu Bhalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to make some changes that it will work good .

So While entering data in Address Column you need to maintain a structure Everytime you insert data maintain that structure then you can select your desired result with query below -

```
SELECT Mid(Title, Instr(Title, 'Day') + 4, Instr(Title, '|')- Instr(Title, ':')-1) As LastName FROM tblblog
```

**My Address Column Value in Database is as below**

```
Address

House No:29| Street No:4| Country:India| City:Ludhiana| Day:Thursday|
```

In that way you can search for country , city as well and it works for other values also .

**Explanation :**

**The Instr function**

It is often used in combination with other string functions for manipulating string values. The Instr function returns the position of a string occurring within another string. The format of the function is as follows:

**Instr ( [start], stringToSearch, stringToFind)**

The start parameter is optional and specifies where in the string we will start searching for the second string. If we wanted to start at the fifth character of the first string then we would specify 5 for the start parameter. If this is left blank then the search is started at the beginning of the first string.

**The Mid Function**

**The Mid(string, start, length)** function returns a portion of a string starting from a specified position and containing a specified number of characters.

The following extracts the month value from a string column in the format dd/mm/yy. The extracted string starts at the 4th character in the string and ends after 2 characters.

Comment: i think Column Value structure you suggested is good i should go with it looks promising to use . Thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the city name is starting with comma(,):

```
      SELECT
      LEFT(Address, CHARINDEX(',', Address)-1) as city,
      SUBSTRING(Address, CHARINDEX(',', Address)+1,
      LEN(Address) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Address)) - CHARINDEX(',', Address)
      )  as state,
      RIGHT(Address, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Address)) - 1) as zip
```

It gets the city as the beginning of the string to the comma.
The zip is the end of the string going backwards until if finds the first  space, so a zip of 19702 or 19702-1234 will work.
The state is anything between the comma and last space in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I created this. It will separate all your values. You forgot to mention the `Area` so I added it also.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3e9f/10)**</kbd>

```
select 
    substring_index(substring_index(Address, ',', 1),',',-1) as street_no,
    substring_index(substring_index(Address, ',', 2),',',-1) as house_no,
    substring_index(substring_index(Address, ',', 3),',',-1) as area,
    substring_index(substring_index(Address, ',', 4),',',-1) as city,
    substring_index(substring_index(Address, ',', 5),',',-1) as state,
    substring_index(substring_index(Address, ',', 6),',',-1) as country,
    substring_index(substring_index(Address, ',', 7),',',-1) as day,
    STR_TO_DATE(trim(substring_index(substring_index(Address, ',', 8),',',-1)),'%d %b %Y') as date1
from table1
```

Output

```
+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
|  street_no  |  house_no   |     area      |   city   | state  | country |    day     |         date1         |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
| Street No-4 | House No-29 | Prabhat Nagar | Ludhiana | Punjab | India   | wednessday | May, 25 2014 00:00:00 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: query is looking good , Thanks for the answer and time you devoted .

Comment: No Problem. Please accept the answer which worked for you the best, so the question can be closed. Thanks.